# Start and end of a period

Tags: python

Is there a way to extend `get_month_day_range()` function   with `week` and `year` in addition to month?

The method could be define as `get_day_range(period, date)` which period could be either `week`, `month` or `year`.

```
import datetime

from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def get_month_day_range(date):
    """
    For a date 'date' returns the start and end date for the month of 'date'.

    Month with 31 days:
    >>> date = datetime.date(2011, 7, 27)
    >>> get_month_day_range(date)
    (datetime.date(2011, 7, 1), datetime.date(2011, 7, 31))

    Month with 28 days:
    >>> date = datetime.date(2011, 2, 15)
    >>> get_month_day_range(date)
    (datetime.date(2011, 2, 1), datetime.date(2011, 2, 28))
    """
    last_day = date + relativedelta(day=1, months=+1, days=-1)
    first_day = date + relativedelta(day=1)
    return first_day, last_day

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

I have got this result so far :

```
def get_period_day_range(date, period='month'):
        last_day = None
        first_day = date + relativedelta(day=1)

        if period == 'month':
            last_day = date + relativedelta(day=1, months=1, days=-1)
        elif period == 'week':
            last_day = date + relativedelta(day=1, weeks=1, days=-1)
        elif period == 'year':
            last_day = date + relativedelta(day=1, years=1, days=-1)
        return first_day, last_day
```

It is not working all the time. It is not working with `week` for `datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 10)` and with `year` for `datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 5)`. How could I fix it? Any suggestions?

Be aware that the function will have of purposes to give us the start and end date of a certain period depending of what date we pass in input. For instance, if I give datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 10) with year, it will give me `(datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1), datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 31))` or with week for `datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 5)` the output will be `(datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 2), datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 8))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing it wrong, just copying the code above without looking at the documentation of the library you are using (link: http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html)

You need to do something like this (not tested):

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import *

def get_period_day_range(date, period='month'):
    if period == 'month':
        # Then we want day 1 of that month and previous day of the 
        # day 1 of the next month, hence months = 1 (next month) and
        # days = -1 (previous date)
        first_day = date + relativedelta(day=1)
        last_day = date + relativedelta(day=1, months=1, days=-1)
    elif period == 'week':
        # Last monday
        first_day = date + relativedelta(weekday=MO(-1))
        # Next sunday
        last_day = date + relativedelta(weekday=SU)
    elif period == 'year':
        # First day of the year, note day and month are singular so they
        # are not relative terms (read the doc)
        first_day = date + relativedelta(day=1, month=1)
        # Last day is always 31 December
        last_day = date + relativedelta(day=31, month=12)
    return first_day, last_day
```